# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN and domain is resolving

Tags: php, mysql, vps

I hosted my PHP website on GoDaddy's Gen 4 VPS. after a while of users using it. The website couldn't be accessed by anyone and all the users received DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. The Nameservers were pointed to the server IP and it was working fine. But when this message appears the domain was resolving, server was working and files could be accessed but when trying to open anything on this domain the users receive DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. When restarting the VPS everything works fine. but this problem happens again and again after users use this website again.

Is there any solution for this or even does anyone faced this problem before or knows the root cause of it??

NOTE: The PHP code was tested before launching and the server specs were more than required.

Comment: Are you able to ping your domain? Are you sure you have pointed your domain to correct IP address?

Comment: yes i tried pinging and everything was fine, server was working and I could access files through cPanel but when accessing it through the domain name I got the message mentioned above in the question, it was also directed to the correct IP and it was working and this message appeared after more than 10 days of directing to the correct IP. this got me crazy, I didn't see anything to cause this problem. but thanks for your response by the way

Comment: Glad to help you. Based on my experience, it is network issue. Have you asked Godaddy team to help to check it for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried connecting from other devices connected to another networks and the users as well had the same problem over another networks so it's related to server I think but I don't exactly know what the problem is, GoDaddy support didn't help me at all, I contacted them more than 25 times but they didn't give me any reason for that or even found the problem, worst support I have ever contacted ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: Change your hosting provider if they can't help you. I would recommend you to check Asphostportal, I personally use their services.

Comment: I will try Asphostportal next time. thanks for your support and time